# How do I keep track of values in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I am new to Prolog and am having some difficulties coming from OOP. I need to recursively run through some characters, but remember what I have gone through. In OOP I would just create an array or arraylist to keep track of anything I have used. However, I can't seem to find a similar way to do this in Prolog. How would I check to see what I've used already.

The exact problem is I want to run through a set of characters and stop if I come to the same one twice essentially. My thought was to add each one to a list and check to see if the next one is a member of the list.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: It would really help if you showed a concrete example of a problem and how you expect your program to behave on it. Otherwise, all you will get is generic suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on @Boris's answer; you could also preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) by using the goal `maplist(dif(X),Seen)` instead of `\+ memberchk(X,Seen)`:

```
foo([],_).                   % 1
foo([X|Xs],Seen) :-          % 2
    maplist(dif(X),Seen),    % 3
    foo(Xs,[X|Seen]).        % 4
```

Comment: For pragmatic reasons, I would delay the choice of implementation until the problem has been properly defined :) but a great answer anyway (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The most basic implementation:

```
foo([], _).                  % 1
foo([X|Xs], Seen) :-         % 2
    \+ memberchk(X, Seen),   % 3
    foo(Xs, [X|Seen]).       % 4
```

- The predicate succeeds when the list is empty (1).
- If the list is not empty (2):

  - check if the first element of the list has already been seen (3)
  - if not (`\+ X` stands for "succeed when X fails"), add the element to the list of seen elements and check the rest of the list (4).

But this is not something you should actually write I think? Since it is not clear what your final goal is, it is difficult to suggest a better solution.

Some hints:

- if you just want to see if there are duplicates in a list, you can [sort and compare lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374711/exactly-one-pair-in-prolog-list/19375092#19375092);
- consider using an [ordset](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ordsets) instead of a list for the second argument;
- figure out what ["accumulators"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944969/prolog-accumulators-are-they-really-a-different-concept/19946885#19946885) are.

Comment: @repeat Yes, might be a better way to do it, and I explicitly said in my answer that I would not actually write code like this. But for this particular _question_ I don't think that introducing both `maplist` and `dif` improves the answer. I would actually suggest you write an answer of your own, for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful: [Prolog iterating over list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048395/prolog-iterating-over-list)  Essentially, Prolog does not have iteration, but it does have recursion.  You will need to recurse through the list to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I realize that I have to use recursion, but how do I keep track of values as I go? I don't understand how the link helps. Is there a way to initialize a list to the empty list and add a character after every recursive call?

Comment: @Jon, yes that's exactly a common way of doing it in Prolog. Starting your recursion with an empty list and each recursive call can add an item to the list. For example, if you pass in the list `L` as an argument, you can add `X` to the head just by referring to `[X|L]`.

Comment: @lurker, How would I create an empty array? I tried to make a predicate start([]). but that just reset the list to an empty array every time I passed it.

Comment: @Jon Prolog doesn't have arrays. It has lists. :) You need to carry an extra argument: `start([], Result)` or something like that. Since you haven't given a specific example in your posted problem description what you're doing, I'm not sure how to be more specific than that. You should Google search "99 prolog problems". A number of them deal with lists and it gives the answers. Then you will get the hang of basic list processing.

Comment: Yeah, I meant list. Still thinking in other languages I guess. But thank you, at least I know I'm heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is how to find the suffix of the list that starts with the first repeated element. If I am right, the implementation can be along the following lines: find an element that is repeated and use for that a predicate that returns the required suffix or fails, and if there are no duplicates the suffix is empty. An implementation that assumes the first argument to be a properly closed list with no free variables can be

```
stop([],[]).
stop([X|R],Rr) :-
  stop_at(R,X,Rr), !.
stop([_|R],Rr) :-
  stop(R,Rr).

stop_at([X|R],X,[X|R]) :- !.
stop_at([_|R],X,Rr) :-
  stop_at(R,X,Rr).
```

Sample runs:

```
?- stop([a,b,c],R).
R = [] ? ;
no
?- stop([a,b,c,d,a,e,a,e],R).
R = [a,e,a,e] ? ;
no
?- stop([b,c,d,c,e],R).
R = [c,e] ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding each found character to a list and then using this list to check if you got a character twice will be linear on the size of the list of of found characters. This may or may not be acceptable w.r.t. performance. How many different characters you have? Only ASCII printable characters? Full Unicode? As only some Prolog systems provide arrays, your next best bet for better performance than lists would be a binary search tree, which will give you O(log(n)) in the average case. But you can do better. As you tagged your question `swi-prolog`, you can use this system read-black tree library (inherited from YAP). This should provide you also with O(log(n)) in the worst case. Using this library (as an alternative to using lists as in the other answers), you could write something along the lines:

```
:- use_module(library(rbtrees)).

foo(List) :-
    rb_new(Seen),
    foo(List, Seen).

foo([], _).
foo([Head| Tail], Seen) :-
    (   rb_lookup(Head, _, Seen) ->
        true
    ;   rb_insert(Seen, Head, _, Seen2),
        foo(Tail, Seen2) 
    ).
```

Is this a worthy (performance-wise) alternative to using a list? You don't provide enough details to answer that. Best to run some tests. Also worth noting that insertion in a list is O(1) (when you do `Head` + `List` -> `[Head| List]`) but insertion in a red-black tree is O(log(n)).